# How to design doted round using android xml

Tags: java, android

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid
        android:color="#D3D3D3"/>
      </shape>
```

above one is single round, how to create two colored round (one inside one) shape using android xml

help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need the stroke tag:

```
<stroke
        android:width="integer"
        android:color="color"
        android:dashWidth="integer"
        android:dashGap="integer" />
```

in particular `android:dashWidth="integer"` and `android:dashGap="integer"`.

The former is the size of each dash line, the latter is the distance between line dashes,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#D3D3D3"/>
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFF0000"
        android:dashWidth="3dp"
        android:dashGap="3dp"/>
 </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i draw a dotted round

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0000FF"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:dashGap="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android:shape="ring"
```

instead of "oval" & then set the inner and outer radius accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oval, and create it like this:

```
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#55FF3300"/>
<size android:height="80dp" android:width="80dp"/>
<stroke android:color="#66FF3300" android:width="10dp"/>

</shape>
```